# Make all HTML elements sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make all the HTML elements sortable.I want to create such a web page that all of its components are sortable. something like [this](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html).

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a plugin, like the one you linked. https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ is another option. Check out the documentation provided for each

Comment: But these are limited to lists only, I want to make all  elements(div,buttons,forms etc) sortable.

Comment: They can work with anything, here's a working example of JQuery sortable working with divs https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets